# How to display custom message in console when your custom module is successfully installed?

Tags: magento2, installation, third-party-module, messages

I am wondering how to display a custom message when installing your own custom module by presumably using and defining the correct operations in the `InstallSchema` class. Which is the best way to display a custom message. e.g.: You built a custom module that needs some initial configuration from the admin panel, and so you ideally want the user to see the following message after successfully installing it by running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

```
[Vendor_Module] is installed successfully, but you need to enable it and 
configure it from the admin panel in the [Module_Tab_Name] section.
```

How can someone achieve it in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

> You Can Run Command `php bin/magento module:status vendor_name` Wit hHelp of this command You can check wheather the module is enabled or not
>
> Also You Can Enable Module by This Command `php bin/magento module:enable vendor_name`